# Match unicode character in zsh regex

Tags: regex, shell, unicode, zsh

I want to make sure that a variable does not contain a specific character (in this case an 'α'), but the following code fails (returns 1):

```
FOO="test" && [[ $FOO =~ '^[^α]*$' ]]
```

*Edit: Changed the pattern based on feedback from stema below to require matching only “non-'α'” characters from start to end.*

Replacing 'α' with e.g. 'x' works as expected. Why does it fail with an 'α', and how can I make this work?

System info:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)
$ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

*Edit 2: I now tested on a Linux machine running Ubuntu 11.10 with zsh 4.3.11 with identical locale settings, and there it works – i.e. `FOO="test" && [[ $FOO =~ '^[^α]*$' ]]` returns success. I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.2.*

Answer (score 1):

with this regex `.*[^α].*` you can't test that `α` is not in the string. What this is testing is: Is there ONE character in the string that is not a `α`.

If you want to check that there is not this character in the string, do this

```
FOO="test" && [[ $FOO =~ '^[^α]*$' ]]
```

this will check if the complete string from the start to the end consists of non "α" characters.

Comment: Oh, right. So it will not necessarily need to match the whole string. Yeah, then you are right, it should be `FOO="test" && [[ $FOO =~ '^[^α]*$' ]]`. But that still fails. Changing the 'α' to an 'x' succeeds, so there must be something that fails when using the 'α' character here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of expressing this is with a negative look-ahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?!.*α)
```

This is saying "when looking forward from the start, I shouldn't be able to see `α` anywhere.

The advantage of using look-heads is they are non-capturing, so you can combine them with other capturing regexes, eg to find groups of numbers in quotes in input that *doesn't* contain a `α`, use this: `^(?!.*α)"(\d+)"`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I got to similar problem on my build system, while having ZSH version 5.0.2 on my notebook (where Unicode works as expected) and ZSH 4.3.17 on my build system. It seems to me that ZSH 5 does not have the problem with Unicode characters in regular expression patterns.

Specifically, parsing the key/value pair:

```
[[ "revision/author=Ľudovít Lučenič" =~ '^([^=]+)=(.*)$' ]]
echo "$match[1]:$match[2]"
```

renders

```
:                               # ZSH 4.3.17
revision/author:Ľudovít Lučenič # ZSH 5.0.2
```

Also, I assume some shortcoming with ZSH 4 Unicode support in general.

**Update:** after some investigation, I have found out that the dot in regexp does not match the letter 'č' in ZSH 4. Once I updated the pattern to:

```
[[ "revision/author=Ľudovít Lučenič" =~ '^([^=]+)=((.|č)*)$' ]]
echo "$match[1]:$match[2]"
```

I am getting the same result in both ZSH versions. I do not know, though, why exactly this letter is the problem here. However, it may help somebody to work this shortcoming around.